# SPFx - Can't get alert for when a checkbox is checked for a Field Customizer

Tags: spfx

I am a complete beginner to SPFx so I am probably doing something completely wrong. I have a SharePoint list that I have managed to change one of the fields to a checkbox. I want to try to give it an action when it is clicked but I can't seem to get it working. I am just trying to make it output an alert at first. I had something working where an alert was going off for me at one point but not in the matter I was looking for. The following is a screenshot of what I have been trying to work with.
[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to put quotes around the call to `button_click()` in your input's `onCLick` (and you don't need the semi-colon):

```
<input type="checkbox" onClick="button_click()">
```

In general, for *any* attribute of an HTML element, you have to enclose the value in quotes.

---

I was just typing up an edit where I was going to say I didn't think that was actually going to work, because putting the function in the `onClick` like that assumes that the function is available in the global namespace, and having your function in the field customizer (which is presumably a class??? I've never written a field customizer...) will mean it's not available like that.

You could maybe try something like

```
event.domElement.innerHtml = `<input type="checkbox"> APP<br>`;
event.domElement.onClick = this.button_click;
```

or

```
event.domElement.innerHtml = `<input type="checkbox"> APP<br>`;
event.domElement.click = this.button_click;
```

but even if that works, you'd be attaching the click handler to your checkbox's parent `div` (the `domElement`), not to the checkbox itself (the `domElement`'s `innerHtml`).

Another option might be to do something like this:

```
event.domElement.innerHtml = `<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox"> APP<br>`;

document.getElementById("mycheckbox").onclick = this.button_click;
```

but even that has problems I can see:

- You'd need a unique ID for each checkbox, since it appears you are using it in a list view, so unless there is a way to get that item's list ID (or even row number in the view) to encode in the `input`'s ID, you wouldn't be able to distinguish between all the checkboxes that end up in the view.
- Again, since I've never written a field customizer, I don't when setting the `event.domElement.innerHtml` actually makes it into the DOM.  If it's immediate than it might be available to be found by `document.getElementById`, but if there's some other hidden rendering step, then it might not be available yet and calling `document.getElementById` will find nothing.

Comment: Hmm, I changed that and I still don't get an alert pop up. Thanks for the info on needing the quotes and everything though! I attached an additional picture of the list to clarify if I didn't explain what I was working with well enough.

Comment: @NateHam updated my answer.